# Cannot open DTS packages in SQL 2008 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

We are deploying a new MS SQL 2008 R2 x64 server running on Win 2008 R2 x64.  We need to open DTS packages but receive the error:

"SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer components are required to edit DTS packages.  Install the special Web download, "SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer Components" to use this feature."

I spent all day yesterday googling and following every answer I could find including: installing and re-installing the MS SQL Server Backward Compatibility Components (SQLServer2005_BC.msi) and the DTS runtime components (SQLServer2005_DTS.msi), following carefully to modify the PATH variable, copying various DLL files between MSSQL folders, etc.  I cannot seem to get it working.

Has anyone come up against this too and know of something else I can try?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. The elements that were not automatically converted to SSIS objects had to be recreated within BIDS. If you discover the real solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this working, and wanted to share for others.  I went over the instructions again and was looking at this:

To ensure that the DTS designer can be used in SQL Server Management Studio

Copy the files, SEMSFC.DLL, SQLGUI.DLL, and SQLSVC.DLL, from the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn folder to the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE folder.

Copy the files, SEMSFC.RLL, SQLGUI.RLL, and SQLSVC.RLL, from the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\Resources folder to the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Resources\%lang_id% folder. For example, for U.S. English, the lang_id subfolder will be "1033".

I knew that the DTS packages were working on our other servers, so I copied the files from a working server into the exact directories they specify here.  Since we are running a 64-bit version, %Program Files% = Program Files(x86).

Once I copied the files into the directories and opened SSMS 2008, the DTS packages open fine with no error.